# Would this question be ok on the site?

Tags: discussion

#### My question.

I have a laptop obviously, and Windows. I program a lot, and I was wondering what things should I do to optimize its lifetime, and usage. I use Powershell, and CMD, and batch file programming. Any recommendations?

#### Meta Post about the question.

My question would not to be searching for software solutions, or any hardware changes more so a common practice like how to better manage my laptop if you get what I mean? Or is this an IT support question?

Comment: I think this is going to be very opinion based. Everyone's workflows and requirements are different. I don't think it is a good fit for [SU].

Comment: @Burgi What if I asked about what protocols can be done to optimize the computer?

Comment: @EnlightenedFunky - There are better communities to have that discussion.  We are not a forum, it sounds like you want to throw ideas around, that isn’t this community.  Besides, how you optimize a computer, is an extremely broad topic.

Answer (score 4):

There are too many things that can be done to optimise systems for specific situations which would make this too broad for this site.

We also don't know your requirements, and those requirements are likely to be difficult to define with enough detail to avoid opinion based answers. What is optimal for one user is sub-optimal for another, it is nearly impossible to say what is "best" for you.

You would probably be better off searching for your specific tools and how to optimise it using your favourite search engine.

Your question would likely devolve into a discussion of pros and cons of specific things. It lacks a specific problem to solve and is far too open ended.

Per [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask)

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.
>
> Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.

Answer (score 2):

## Your question is completely opinion-based and off-topic.

Your question is :

> “I have a laptop obviously, and Windows. I program a lot, and I was wondering what things should I do to optimize its lifetime, and usage. I use Powershell, and CMD, and batch file programming. Any recommendations?”

Without any specifics, this is already a too broad question. And even with specifics, nobody could ever give you a solid answer. I have programmed on MacBook Air 11” models from 2013, Mac Pro towers and now a MacBook Air (2020) and I have never had issues. It’s not too much different for Windows machines; even the most basic barebones Windows machine can be used for programming.

Besides, the premise of the question is basically:

> “I have decided what I am going to use my laptop for is complicated. Therefore I have also assumed complexity means that the system will be stressed. Therefore what can I do to extend the life of this system.”

None of what you are asking makes any practical sense. And then your meta question doubles down on this; bold emphasis is mine:

> “My question would not to be searching for software solutions, or any hardware changes more so a common practice like how to **better manage my laptop if you get what I mean? Or is this an IT support question?**”

I have no idea what you mean when you say “…better manage my laptop if you get what I mean?”

- Do you really think there is some one “secret” tip to using a laptop for programming?
- Do you believe laptops fail because — for example — a laptop used for writing is not used as “heavily” as a laptop that is used for programming?
- Do you really believe that when laptops die or need repair you need to specify what you have used the laptop for to get it repaired?

The reality is some salespeople and repair people will ask you — honestly — dumb questions like “What did you use this laptop for?” but they only do that to upsell you are repair and replacement parts. Stuff like “Well, you need faster RAM or a better mouse…” and such.

#### While well intentioned, your question is assuming tons of negatives that you are attempting to “prepare” yourself for.

Instead of doing that just buy a laptop you like and don’t let salesman “doubt” questions infect your decision-making.

Comment: I haven't heard any response in a while, and I have been busy with school work. I believe some clarification is due in part to better my post, at least to clarify the answer. Maybe like some technique for file management like a naming system. Dealing with various IDEs, and different file types and keeping things organized. Would any of these be appropriate?

Comment: @EnlightenedFunky - So you want to hear our opinions on the best way to manage files, that type of question, is out of scope.  What IDEs you use or don’t use then that’s completely up to you, seeking our opinions, would be out of scope.  I don’t see any variation of your question being within scope